# Packer CentOS AMI: loop device not found

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ami, packer, amazon-ebs

So I'm trying to make modifications to an ISO in a Packer instance, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
==> amazon-ebs.centos-efi: + sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop 'temporary.iso' /tmp/tmp.M5xCLte5mi
==> amazon-ebs.centos-efi: mount: temporary.iso: failed to setup loop device: No such file or directory
```

And I cannot seem to understand why this is happening. Things I have tried:

- I have tried mounting in a different directory.
- Running `modprobe loop`
- Running `losetup`
- Creating a loop device: `sudo mknod -m640 /dev/loop8 b 7 8`

Neither of them worked. So I've come here for some guidance.

I'll provide relevant bits of my Packer template below:

```
source "amazon-ebs" "centos-efi" {
  ami_name        = "centos-efi-{{timestamp}}"
  ssh_username    = "centos"
  instance_type   = "t2.medium"
  region          = "${var.aws_region}"
  source_ami      = "ami-04f798ca92cc13f74"
  skip_create_ami = true
  tag {
    key   = "Name"
    value = "CentOS EFI Build"
  }
  launch_block_device_mappings {
    device_name           = "/dev/sda1"
    volume_size           = 32
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
}
```

Provisioner Code:

```
ISO_ORIG=$(mktemp -d)
ISO_CHANGE=$(mktemp -d)
ls -al /tmp
sleep 15

sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop temporary.iso $ISO_ORIG
cd $ISO_ORIG
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: What is the provisioner code executing this?

Comment: Is the ISO baked into a custom AMI backed EBS snapshot, or otherwise how is placed onto the EBS filesystem?

Comment: Using a `file` provisioner by Packer